# Change user during session through a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently logged in as admin on an oracle-database and I want to change the user of my session with a query. Is that possible?

Comment: Did you try ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't seems to work when the username contains a "."

Comment: ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_user = user.name generates: "ORA-02248 Invalid option from ALTER session"

Comment: `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA="user.name"`

Comment: I'm getting "user does not exists" but I do know that the user exists.

Comment: Check existence of the user with `select * from all_users where username = "user.name"`

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, [Switching to a Different Schema](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/general.htm#i1107794) with `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = <schema name>` (as suggested in the comments) does not also switch the user, it just lets you avoid specifying the schema in your SQL statements during the session. In Oracle Database, the user and the schema are separate, but every user has the schema.

However you can satisfy your needs implementing [roles](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/authorization.htm#DBSEG99879). You provide privileges to the role and than can use `SET ROLE` statement during your session to switch between the roles with appropriate set of privileges.

Comment: Thanks for your time to write that answer but I found an function in the database that change user during session.

Comment: Mind posting it here? – probably as an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Having encountered the same problem, I found out you can use the [connect](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve015.htm) command to switch users. Note that, for changing in a script, without interactive shell, you need to provide the password in the command. Here is an example

```
-- Some arbitrary scripts executing with an admin role
-- Following is an example of a privileged command
CREATE USER ANOTHER_USER
   IDENTIFIED BY a_weak_password
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO ANOTHER_USER;

-- Now switch to newly created user
CONNECT ANOTHER_USER/a_weak_password
-- Check which user is currently set
SHOW USER
```